# I can't build for android in unity

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, admob, google-mobile-ads

*The game was building without any problems before, but GoogleMobileAds-v7.3.1.unitypackage
This is what happened after I imported it.Is there a problem with the GoogleMobileAds-v7.3.1.unitypackage version? what should I do

These are the errors in the console

Building Library\Bee\artifacts\Android\ManagedStripped failed with output:

UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+BuildMethodException: 3 errors

*

Comment: Make sure to scroll and scan through all of the output. There might be more useful error messages than just that.

Answer (score 0):

You should provide more details about your problem so we can give you a meaningful answer.

Here are a few things you can try:

1. See all details about the error in *Console* window and solve them all
   1.1 If there is no error in the *Console* window, be sure the *Error* button is toggled on (image below)

   [image]

   1.2 If you need more details about your error, run the *Open Editor Log* (image below) and read your error one by one until you find the cause of all errors

[image]

2. If you already had some earlier version of the *GoogleMobileAds* package in the project, remove all folders and files and then import the new one

Comment: My GoogleMobileAds version is up to date and I have shared the errors in the console. I don't understand what to ask because I don't understand what the problem is.